# Prevent useEffect retriggering when updating state from specific function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've the following component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const UndoInput = () => {
    
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    
    return(
        <div className = 'Name'>
            <input  
                onChange = {(e) => setName(e.target.value)} 
                value    = {name}>
            </input>
            <Undo
                name     = {name}
                setName  = {setName}
            />
        </div>
    );
    
}

export default UndoInput;
```

The `<Undo/>` component is a buffer storing the value of an input on every change, allowing to perform an undo action.

```js
const Undo = ({name, setName}) => {
    
    const [buffer, setBuffer] = useState(['', '', '']);
    const [index,  setIndex]  = useState(-1);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        let copy = [...buffer, name].slice(-3);
        
        let pos = index + 1;
        
        if(pos > 2)
            pos = 2;
        
        setBuffer(copy);
        setIndex(pos);
        
    }, [name]);
    
    const undo = () => {
        
        let pos = index - 1;
        
        if(pos < 0)
            pos = -1;
        
        setName(buffer[pos]);
        setIndex(pos);
        
    }
    
    return(
        <button onClick = {undo}>Undo</button>
    );
    
}
```

Example:

If a user types 'abc' on the input, `buffer = ['a', 'ab', 'abc']` and `index = 2`.

When a user clicks on the button, the component should go back to the previous state. That means, `buffer = ['a', 'ab', 'abc']` and `index = 1`.

After clicking on the button, `setName(buffer[pos])` is executed, the `useEffect()` is retriggered: `buffer = ['ab', 'abc', 'ab']` and `index = 2` (not desired).

How can I prevent to retrigger the `useEffect()` Hook, iff it was retriggered by the `undo()` function?

Comment: I think your problem is the logic itself and not the useEffect retriggering when name changes. If I understand you correctly, you want your undo button to change only the index and not modify the buffer, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, right. Undo button: change index, not modify the buffer and update the name variable. Bear in mind, that I only have control over the 'Undo' component, so I can't set the buffer and index on the main component.

Comment: And suppose buffer = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'], if undo is pressed twice do you want to have 'abc' or 'a'?

Comment: Is it an option for you to scrap your `<Undo />` component approach and just use a custom hook `useUndoableState`?

Comment: Supposing buffer = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'], by pressing twice undo, I want to have 'a' on the input, index = 0 and buffer = ['a', 'ab', 'abc'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use useEffect for this. Your undo buffer is not, in my humble opinion, a side-effect in the React DOM sense, but rather internal logic you want to apply on state change. Likewise, your Undo component is a button that also happens to have reusable logic about history and state that arguably belongs more to the parent than the button itself.

Overall, I think this approach is not a clean top-down flow, and tends to lead to this kind of problems in React.

I would instead start by putting your undo logic and state in the parent:

```
const handleChange = function(e){
   // add to undo buffer here
   setName(e.target.value);
}
const handleUndo = function(){
   // fetch your undo buffer here
   setName(undoValue);
}
onChange = {handleChange} 
onClick = {handleUndo}
```

After wiring up everything, you'll probably feel that you lost the clean reusability of your Undo component by doing that and you'd be right. But this is exactly what [Custom Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) are for: reusable stateful logic. There are many ways ways to go about it, but here's an example of a custom hook you could write:

```
const [name, setName, undoName] = useUndoableState('');
```

The hook would replace useState (and use it itself inside the hook), manage the buffer, and provide an additional function to call undo that rewinds and set the new name.

```
<input onChange={setName} />
<button onClick={undoName}>Undo</button>
```